# Node voltage equation, is it right?

Tags: nodal-analysis

I have this scheme.[image]

I have calculated the resistance of coil and capacitors. This is the source: [image]

And here are my equations about the **upper node(U1)**. Are they right?

[image]

Comment: Upper node (U1) - where is it in your scheme?

Comment: There are 2 nodes, the bottom one is grounded.

Comment: There are 5 nodes and two along the top. Please don't try and be too clever.

Answer (score 0):

Your next to last line left hand side should be: -0.02U1 + 0.1 else eqns to here ok. If final algebra follows, ok.